# Exercise 8(a), Section 20 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ consisting of all sequences $x$ such that $\sum x_i^2$ converges. Then the formula
> $$ d( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} ) = \left[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( x_i - y_i \right)^2 \right]^{1/2} $$
> defines a metric on $X$. . . . On $X$ we have the three topologies it inherits from the box, uniform, and product topologies on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. We have also the topology given by the metric $d$, which we call the $\ell^2$-topology. . . .
>
> (a) Show that on $X$, we have the inclusions
> $$ \mbox{ box topology } \supset \ell^2\mbox{-topology } \supset \mbox{ uniform topology}.  $$

**My attempt:** we first show $\mathcal{T}_{\overline{\rho}}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_{l^2}$. Let $d’$ be a Euclidean metric on $\Bbb{R}$. $0\leq (d’(x_j,y_j))^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (d’(x_i,y_i))^2,=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i-y_i|^2, \forall j\in \Bbb{N}$. Since square root map is monotonically increasing, we have $d’(x_j,y_j)\leq d(x,y), \forall j\in \Bbb{N}$. So $\overline{d’}(x_j,y_j)\leq d’(x_j,y_j)\leq d(x,y), \forall j\in \Bbb{N}$. Thus $\sup_{j\in \Bbb{N}} \{\overline{d’}(x_j,y_j) \}=\overline{\rho}(x,y)\leq d(x,y), \forall x,y \in X$. By theorem 20.3 and $\overline{\rho}(x,y)\leq d(x,y)$ inequality, we have $\mathcal{T}_{\overline{\rho}}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_{l^2}$, our desired  result. **Is this proof correct?**

Proof of $\mathcal{T}_{b}\supseteq \mathcal{T}_{l^2}$ is in [Prob. 8, Sec. 20 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The topology of $\ell^2$ in comparison with the box and uniform topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996666/861687).

Comment: Just a side note: Interestingly enough, $\ell^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ with product topology, but the two are different as topological vector spaces, the latter not having an admissible norm.

Comment: @Jakobian I’m sorry I don’t understand some terms like topological vector space and admissible norm.

Comment: You can safely ignore my comment.

Comment: @PaulSinclair what is $\rho$ and $d$ metric represent? Anyway  you have actually shown $\mathcal{T}_{\rho} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_d$, not $\mathcal{T}_{\rho} \supseteq \mathcal{T}_d$!

Comment: They represent exactly what I said in the comment: two metrics with $\rho \le d$ everywhere. But you are right. I was turning around the topology relation.